# Super Collider Autocompletion Not Working

Tags: supercollider

My Super Collider Autocomplete is not auto popping up when I typed at least 3 characters when creating a method. I was able to make the list appear when using the shortcut "Trigger Autocompletion" but it does not pop up automatically like my classmates do. I tried to install different versions of Super Collider but the problem still persists. I use a 2017 MacBook pro with mac OS Big Sur. I’d greatly appreciate it if anyone can help.

Image of Autocompletion List

[image: 1]

Comment: What version of SuperCollider are you using?  Is it 3.12.2 or 3.13.0-rc2?  If it's the RC, you might try going to the stable version, 3.12.2.  If that doesn't help, you might also try deleting the folder ~/Library/Application\ Support/SuperCollider

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm looking at the right place, but I can't find that folder. Also, I tried installing multiple versions of SuperCollider but it still doesn't work. My current version is 3.12.2

Comment: That folder is hidden, so you may need to navigate to it from the terminal.

The problem you're running into sounds like a bug, so I'd like to encourage you to please file a bug report with the project. https://github.com/supercollider/supercollider/issues/new?assignees=&labels=bug&template=bug_report.md&title= .  If someone there suggests a solution, please let us know here what they said and if it worked.